# Create an installable trigger in a script from another script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

After months of trying, I can't get it.

Let me explain what I need:

I have a spreadsheet from which executing a function duplicates an existing template with a script. The script of the template that I duplicate has a series of functions, among which there is one that is in charge of setting a trigger, something like this:

```
function setMyTrigger() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
        .timeBased()
        .everyMinutes(1)
        .create();
}
```

I would like that in the process of duplicating that template from my core document, once duplicated, the same function executes `setMyTrigger()` in the script of the new duplicated spreadsheet, saving in its script the corresponding trigger.

To summarize:

1. I execute a function in my central document. This function by steps does the following:

   a) Duplicates the template

   b) Accesses the script of the new Spreadsheet and executes the function `setMyTrigger()`. This function has to set the trigger in that same script.

ChatGPT is telling me there is no way to do this automatically with a single function without manually intervening in the process. Hopefully, this is a lie, and there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Who is going authorize the scripts in the template copy?

Comment: That authorization would have to be part of the function (if possible) and the owner of the trigger would have to be me.

Comment: The owner of the trigger has to be the owner of the project that it's in.  And a function cannot authorized it requires a user to fill out the dialogs.  There is no way too circumvent the security of authorization.

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible to create a Spreadsheet from a central document and that the new document created contains its script and triggers from the moment of its creation? Would a manual intervention always be necessary? It seems to me something very little scalable :/

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think that if the document is shared with another use then that user has to choose whether of not to accept the use of said script functions and triggers. I may be overstepping here and I'm prepared to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited to using Google Apps Script services, this time ChatGPT is correct.

To implement something close to your design, you should use more tools like the Google Apps Script API; however, you might change your design. Instead of using the bounded script, you might use Google Sheets Add-on.